# Python : could not convert string to float error

Tags: python, string, numpy

I have CSV file with [NEAR_DIST] (<-row 7). I would like to know how can I get the mean and STD of this array.

I used CSV and numpy:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import numpy

with open('C:\\test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    distance = []
    distance.append(float(x) for x in csvfile)
    for row in readCSV:
        distance = row[7]
        a = numpy.array(distance, dtype = 'float_')
        b = numpy.sum(a)
        print(b)
```

Comment: Example of few rows form the file would be useful.

Comment: What @Marcin said as well as the exact error with the line and such would be helpful for someone who wants to answer you.

Comment: Also, use `numpy.genfromtxt` instead of python `csv` for a more natural and probably faster performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little unclear.
My assumption is that you have some data of the form:

01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,..
11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,..
21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,..
and you want to find the sum of elements in the 7th column. i.e. 7 + 17 + 27 + ... in this example.

This should work:

```
import numpy
data = numpy.genfromtxt("a.csv", delimiter=",")
data[:, 6].sum() # 6 because indices start from 0 in python
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question and code correctly, you want to read the seventh row in your .csv file. This is not done with your row[7] statement. If you do:

```
for row in readCSV:
```

You will go through all the lines in your .csv file, reading one at a time and storing it as `row`. With a delimiter (in this case, a comma) everything between commas will be added to a list. For example the line `"0,12,23,37.154,444"` in your csv file would end up in the following list: `[0,12,23,37.154,444]` with 5 elements.

When you access `row[7]`, you are taking the eight column of your current `row` in the loop (remember that Python starts counting at 0).

Also, your `distance` variable that you define in the beginning is overwritten by the `distance` variable in your `for row in readCSV:` loop.

So, in case you wanted the seventh row in your file, I suggest working with a counter that counts how many rows you have already passed. If it has reached the seventh row, it just adds up all the numbers of that row and stores them:

```
import csv
with open('C:\\test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

    # Create counter variable to count rows
    rowCounter = 0

    # Create distance variable to sum distances later
    distance = 0

    # Go through each row in the csv file
    for row in readCSV:
        rowCounter += 1 # Add one to the rowCounter
        if rowCounter == 7: # If rowCounter is seventh row
            for e in row: # For every element in this row
                distance += float(e) # Add the float of that element to distance
```

If this was unhelpful, I suggest being more specific in your question.